# LINQ Query generates unnecessarily long SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a bunch of Services, who references Students (many to one), who references StudentEnrollments (one to many).

When I query these services, it is generating SQL that contains 2 blocks that looks the same which slows down performance. I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Here is my C# Code (narrowed down):

```
IQueryable<StudentServiceDm> query = GetListQuery();

List<int> schoolIds = // from front-end: in this case: 20, 21, 22, 23, 89, 90, 93, 95
query = query.Where(m => m.Student.StudentEnrollments.Any(s => schoolIds.Contains(s.SchoolId.Value)));

IQueryable<StudentServiceDto> dtoQuery = query.Select(m => new StudentServiceDto
{
    Id = m.Id,
    Name = m.Name,
    ParentParticipationCount = m.ParentCount,
    StudentFirstName = m.Student.FirstName,
    StudentLastName = m.Student.LastName,
    StudentId = m.StudentId.Value,
    StudentServiceType = m.StudentServiceType.Name,
    StudentServiceSubType = m.StudentServiceSubType.Name,
    Date = m.Date,
    DurationInMinutes = m.DurationInMinutes
});

return dtoQuery;
```

Here is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[ParentCount] AS [ParentCount], 
    [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Extent1].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name2], 
    [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent1].[DurationInMinutes] AS [DurationInMinutes]
    FROM    [dbo].[StudentService] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent1].[StudentId] = [Extent2].[Id])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[StudentServiceType] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent1].[StudentServiceTypeId] = [Extent3].[Id])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[StudentServiceSubType] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent4].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent1].[StudentServiceSubTypeId] = [Extent4].[Id])
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Deleted] = 0) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[StudentEnrollment] AS [Extent5]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent6].[Id] = [Extent5].[StudentId]
        WHERE ([Extent6].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent1].[StudentId] = [Extent6].[Id]) AND ([Extent5].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent5].[SchoolId] IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 89, 90, 93, 95))
    )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[StudentEnrollment] AS [Extent7]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent8].[Id] = [Extent7].[StudentId]
        WHERE ([Extent8].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent1].[StudentId] = [Extent8].[Id]) AND ([Extent7].[Deleted] = 0) AND ([Extent7].[SchoolId] IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 89, 90, 93, 95))
    ))
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Date] DESC, [Extent1].[Id] ASC
    OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

As you can see, the SQL is doing two boolean blocks (A AND B) where A and B looks exactly the same (with the [extend] suffix being different of course). I think my query is simple enough as to not confuse LINQ to generate such query. Can any expert tell me why this is happening? Or How I can write my query in another way.

Comment: How much does it slow down performance? It's clearly not what one would write by hand, but I would have expected the database's query analyser to make short work of removing the duplication.

Comment: its a 0.5 second vs 3 seconds difference when i run that query in the database manually.

Comment: Welcome to the party, pal :-)

Comment: @buffjape of what? shitty LINQ?

Comment: LINQ never claims to write the most efficient SQL.  If performance is that bad, then write it in SQL directly or for the masochist, write your own LINQ to SQL interpreter.

Comment: What is your `GetListQuery()` method? If you're adding a bunch of `.Include()`s, then you're going to slow your process down.

Comment: @krillgar nothing is in there, it is basically just the context's AsQueryable() for the StudentServiceDm

Comment: @chambo thanks for the constructive comment. So you're saying if i have a problem here I should just delete my application and rewrite it in SQL by hand like with PHP 10 years ago, right? Thanks

Comment: That's disappointing on the part of the database. Can you show what `GetListQuery` does? It might give more insight into why the provider feels the need to double up on that bit.

Comment: @JonHanna It really only does something like this dbContext.Set<StudentServiceDm>().AsQueryable(); But since it can be any datamodels i've put in into GetListQuery() in a StudentServiceBo that accepts a type T.

Comment: @andyh0316 - I wouldn't go that far, but if LINQ can't make heads or tails of your query and produces SQL output that is wholly inefficient then your best bet is usually to write it in SQL to bypass the LINQ inefficiencies.

Comment: I wonder if removing the `StudentLastName` field would fix that. Obviously that's no good as an overall solution as you need that field, but I'm wondering if it's feeling the need to match the criteria on `Students` for each select from `Students`.

Comment: @JonHanna I removed everything but the Id, still the same =(

Comment: As others have suggested, LINQ isn't really all that efficient.  It works well for querying against small pieces of data (or for what I use it for, more often than not, querying against data tables that already exist in memory).  I've mostly abandoned the idea of using it to query against databases directly as it is that inefficient at it.  I can understand the frustration, but not every tool is meant for every job.  In this case, writing pure SQL sounds like a better alternative.

Comment: @user2366842 just curious. What do you use instead of LINQ? Or do you know something that's pretty readable and also fast? I really don't want to be writing SQLs everywhere it feels like what I had to do 10 years ago.

Comment: If I need efficiency?  either parameterized inline SQL or stored procs (if I need re-usability).  I get that's probably not what you want as an answer, but that's about as good as you can get for database speed.

Comment: @user2366842 that's a shame. I really enjoy the strongly typed nature of LINQ. And that if a parameter name is changed, it will warn me and i dont have to go into the database to write all these unreadable stored proc SQL.

Comment: If something's "good enough" in LINQ, then by all means, leave it be, but if it's too slow to be viable, you're often better off just hitting against the database directly with well optimized SQL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the posted SQL is not generated by the standard EF query translator (all these `Deleted` conditions). Most likely you are using some 3rd party query interception library or the source LINQ query is quite different from posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework makes little attempt to optimize the SQL being generated - quite the opposite in practice. It's meant to be convenient rather than fast.

LINQ and Entity Framework are free, but Windows Azure charges by the second for database access. The slower the queries are, the more money Microsoft makes. 
So I'm sure Microsoft are working really, really hard to speed it up for you.

If you need speed but cannot get it from EF, there are options:

- Write a SQL stored procedure or SQL view - both can be called from Entity Framework.
- Write your own query in SQL and execute it using ADO.NET
- Fiddle around with the LINQ query until it speeds up by itself

Comment: I understand that LINQ is not the most optimized. But in this case I'm just trying to paginate through a list of services, My query is simple enough im not really writing a report query here with 20 joins and intersections. If it takes 3 seconds to paginate through a simple query when it can be done in less than 0.5 seconds then I wonder why LINQ is so highly praised.

Comment: It's the allure of functional programming. Looks cool and type-checked. Everyone imagines it's doing wonderful optimizations behind the scenes.. Plus Microsoft are very good at promoting their technologies.

Comment: @andyh0316: because (when it works) 1) it doesn't require developers to learn T-SQL, let alone how to write optimized T-SQL, which is a skill of its own and 2) because it obviates the need for writing code that will map your tables into objects, which is typically code that is tedious and error-prone. This is why any ORM exists. Note that your beef is specifically with LINQ to EF; LINQ in general is massively useful and I can't imagine any substantial C# code base today that doesn't use LINQ to Objects somewhere (whether or not it uses the special keywords as well).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the explanation. Do you know of any method other than writing SQL straight up? It is tedious and provides no generic implementation of any sort.

Comment: @andyh0316: there are smaller ORMs like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) that remove the tedium of object mapping, while still leaving the actual query writing to you. There are also more fully featured ORMs whose main selling point is that they're not Entity Framework. SO is not the place for software recommendations, but [knock yourself out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET).

Answer (score 0):

```
query = query.Where(m => m.Student.StudentEnrollments.Any(s => schoolIds.Contains(s.SchoolId.Value)));
```

to

```
query = query.Where(a => schoolIds.Any(b => a.Student.StudentEnrollments.Select(c => c.SchoolId.Value).Contains(b)));
```

I flipped the logic and it generates a query that increased the performance. Even though it's longer and not ideal, but at least it is "correct". The first LINQ just for some reason has those 2 duplicated blocks which really kills the performance in this case.